# Performance of CPU

Tags: performance, computer-science, cpu-architecture

While going through Computer organisation by Patterson,I encountered a question where I am completely stuck. Question is:

> Suppose we know that an application that uses both a desktop client and a remote server is limited by network performance. For the following changes state whether only the throughput improves, both response time and throughput improve, or neither improves.

And the changes made are:

> More memory is added to the computer

If we add more memory ,shouldn't the throughput and execution time will improve?

To be clear ,the definition of throughput and response time is explained in the book as:

> Throughput: The amount of work done in a given time.
>
> Response Time: time required to complete a task ,tasks are i/o device activities, Operating System overhead, disk access, memory access.

Comment: *"shouldn't the Throughput and execution time will improve??"* so you already have an answer in mind. Maybe you should lay out your reasons why you think that is the answer. Then someone can tell you whether you're right or wrong instead of just presenting an answer on a silver platter.

Comment: @the8472 thank you .. i will keep it in  ind next time !!!

Comment: why only next time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume the desktop client is your internet browser. And the server is the internet, for example the stackoverflow website. If you're having network performance problems, adding more RAM to your computer won't make browsing the internet faster.

More memory helps only when the application needs more memory. For any other limitation, the additional memory will simply remain unused.

Comment: if it would be a simple computer ,and if we would add more memory ,what effect will it have on Throughput and response time ?Response time should decrease and also throughput should increase ?

Comment: Probably no effect. The processor affects throughput and response time the most. Memory is just capacity of storing data. It's a problem only when it's a limitation (you have too little of it).

Comment: i was wondering ,if we add more memory ,say cache memory then the hit probablity wil be more resulting to fewer page fault.Isn't it imroving the throughput and response time both ?because if there would be more lts page faults then execution time or response time will increase as it have to go to main memory again to read/write the data required.

Comment: Yes, in this case it would work. But it's a very specific corner case. Without knowing for sure you get page faults, adding memory will not help. You're falling into premature optimization. Yes, more memory could help in some cases, but probably won't in general.

Answer (score 0):

You have to think like a text book here. If your only given constraint is network performance, then you have to assume that there are no other constraints.

Therefore, the question boils down to: how does increasing the memory affect network performance?

If you throw in other constraints such as the system is low on memory and actively paging, then maybe response time improves with more memory and less paging. But the only constraint given is network performance.

Comment: if it would be a simple computer ,and if we would add more memory ,what effect will it have on Throughput and response time ?Response time should decrease and also throughput should increase ??

Comment: I just explained why not.

Answer (score 0):

It wont make a difference as you are already bound by the network performance. Imagine you have a large tank of water and tiny pipe coming out it. Suppose you want to get more water within given amount of time (throughput). Does it make sense to add more water to the tank to achieve that? Its not, as we are bound by the width of the pipe. Either you add more pipes or you widen the pipe you have.

Going back to your question, if the whole system is bound by network performance you need to add more bandwidth, to see any improvement. Doing anything else is pointless.